# Push Values from different array to Different Keys

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, array-merge

i have 2 array like this :

```
let payrollname = [{"code": "a1", "name": "Loan A"}, {"code": "a2", "name": "Loan B"}, {"code": "a3", "name": "Loan C"}, {"code": "a4", "name": "Loan D"}, {"code": "a5", "name": "Loan E"}]
```

and

```
let payrollbalance = [{"a1": 0, "a2": 100000, "a3": 500000, "a4": 300000, "a5": 45900}]
```

how can i pushing values from `payrollbalance` to `payrollname` ?

i mean push like this, values from `payrollbalance.a4` which mean `300000` push to `payrollname.code == a4`

and i hope final results can similar like :

```
let result = `[{"code": "a1", "name": "Loan A", "values": 0}, {"code": "a2", "name": "Loan B", , "values": 100000}, {"code": "a3", "name": "Loan C", "values": 500000}, {"code": "a4", "name": "Loan D", "values": 300000}, {"code": "a5", "name": "Loan E",  "values": 45900}]`
```

any help will be appricated, im already messing up whole days.

thanks in advance

Comment: Is there a reason `payrollbalance` is an array? Can it have more than one object?

Comment: @Nick Parsons no, only 1 length . and always.

Comment: Ok, can you also add your attempts to far (even if they don't work?) then you can see where you went wrong

Comment: @NickParsons im trying to manipulate render at front end (because i cant change their backend) ```like this.state.payrollbalance+'.a4'``` but return always be ```[object Object].a4```

Comment: @Tumbalakun Better to share attempt for such question and find out what went wrong instead of expecting someone to solve it for you. Till now you have been messing up whole day, If someone solve it for you then you will be messing up for whole life.

Comment: @Tumbalakun hm, could you update your question with your attempt (you can press the edit button to add it in)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and add `values` key with the value of payrollbalance[0] with indicating the json key by `[]` for dynamic.

```js
let payrollname = [{"code": "a1", "name": "Loan A"}, {"code": "a2", "name": "Loan B"}, {"code": "a3", "name": "Loan C"}, {"code": "a4", "name": "Loan D"}, {"code": "a5", "name": "Loan E"}]

let payrollbalance = [{"a1": 0, "a2": 100000, "a3": 500000, "a4": 300000, "a5": 45900}]

let result = payrollname.map(item => ({
  ...item,
  values: payrollbalance[0][item.code]
}));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Make an array seach, find the index and change it after

```js
let payrollname = [{"code": "a1", "name": "Loan A"}, {"code": "a2", "name": "Loan B"}, {"code": "a3", "name": "Loan C"}, {"code": "a4", "name": "Loan D"}, {"code": "a5", "name": "Loan E"}]
let payrollbalance = [{"a1": 0, "a2": 100000, "a3": 500000, "a4": 300000, "a5": 45900}]
var result = [];
let pblance = payrollbalance[0]
for(let p in pblance)
{
  let index = payrollname.findIndex(el => el.code==p)
  let pname = payrollname[index]
  pname.values = pblance[p];
  result.push(pname)
}
console.log(result);
```

Comment: since you did findindex inside for() loop, the o notation will be o(n*n), that the performance is not good.

Comment: @WilliamWang i should use `.indexOf` instead of `findIndex`

Comment: no, it's same. `indexOf` also iterate the array.

Comment: you can just call the object dynamic key using `[]`. refer to above my answer.

Answer (score 0):

this code will work !

```js
let payrollname = [{"code": "a1", "name": "Loan A"}, {"code": "a2", "name": "Loan B"}, {"code": "a3", "name": "Loan C"}, {"code": "a4", "name": "Loan D"}, {"code": "a5", "name": "Loan E"}]
let payrollbalance = [{"a1": 0, "a2": 100000, "a3": 500000, "a4": 300000, "a5": 45900}]
let result = []
let i = 0
payrollname.forEach(element => {
    let value = payrollbalance[0][element.code]
    element.values = value;
    result[i] = element
    i=i+1
});
console.log(result)
```